# Index convention according to Schwartz

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

On page 15 of his QFT book, Schwartz writes that all the following contractions are equivalent as long as the flat metric is used: $$v^\mu w_\mu=v_\mu w^\mu=v_\mu w_\mu=v^\mu w^\mu.$$ Isn't this false? For example, expanding the sums we get $ v^\mu w^\mu=v^0w^0+v^1w^1+v^2w^2+v^3w^3$, but $$v^\mu w_\mu=v^0w_0+v^1w_1+v^2w_2+v^3w_3=v^0w^0-v^1w^1-v^2w^2-v^3w^3 $$ since $w_j=-w^j$ for $j=1,2,3$.

What's the catch?

Comment: Well, I would say that what he said is incorrect. Suppose you start with a vector with components $v^\mu$. Then the associated one-form has components *defined* by the equation $v_\mu = \eta_{\mu\nu}v^\nu$, and in that case $v_0 = v^0$ and $v_i = -v^i$. In that case your argument is clearly correct.

Comment: @Gold I had a similar doubt when my professor expanded a scalar product of the form $\boldsymbol \alpha\cdot \boldsymbol \nabla$ as $\alpha^j\partial^j$. Shouldn't we always put these indexes one up and one down, as $\alpha^j \partial_j$? I guess the reason we got away with it, is because ultimately the expression was to be squared and $$ \alpha^j\partial^j\alpha^k\partial^k=\alpha^j\eta^{jn}\partial_n\alpha^k\eta^{km}\partial_m,$$ but of course for spatial indexes $\eta^{ab}=-\delta^{ab}$ and so this is equivalent to the 'correct' expression $\alpha^j\partial_j\alpha^k\partial_k$.

Comment: It's just a convention that book is employing. Since in the entirety of the book, he exclusively works in $(+,-,-,-)$ signature he simply DEFINES $a_\mu b_\mu \equiv a^0 b^0 - \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$. This is simply a convention and definitely not a standard convention at that. However, it is one that he employs and it works for him as well.

Answer (score 2):

I you read it carefully you will understand that Schwartz only does this for ease of notation. He specifically says that index position is important when you plug in explicit vectors or matrices. I.e. he basically says that the reader is smart enough to do the contractions correctly.

But it is indeed rather sloppy and unnecessary if you ask me.